# Announcement For New Languages

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

So, there's been a large influx of Swift related questions (100% all opinion based questions) and that got me thinking.. perhaps keep track of new tags for a specific amount of time (maybe a week or two?), and if somebody asks a question with this tag, present them with a quick (one time) FAQ reminder or something so that we can stop questions like:

"Is Swift better than Objective-C?"

"Should I stop learning Objective-C now?"

Or is there nothing we can do to stop these obviously opinionated questions in the future and as always, close and move on?

I'd rather not be doomed to these typical lazy questions everytime a new language is released.

Comment: They do have a little banner thing that pops up if your question looks too subjective to warn you it might be closed, but it is very unnoticeable and honestly the last time I had it pop up for me, I didn't even notice it until right before I was about to click the Submit button and was looking it over for errors.

Comment: @animuson is that for any question, or questions with newly added wiki tags?

Comment: All questions. Anything you type in that Ask Question page will run through the subjective-o-meter. Though I have no idea how it works at all. It seems like it would pop up for both those examples, but again, it's not very noticeable, so it wouldn't really stop them.

Comment: In my opinion, the release of a new language (from a popular enough vendor) is a rare enough event not to warrant any specific work to be done for this.

Comment: @ChristopheD well the theory could also be applied to plugins as well, which pop up on the daily. Technology moves fast enough that this could be an issue rather quickly.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea, but it just doesn't scale. Who would maintain it each time that some new technology comes out? There's no reason for it to be specific, just make it general: don't ask subjective, opinion-based questions. Oh wait, we already have that rule.

Comment: @CodyGray: As I read it, the suggestion is that the warning would be generic, and would appear any time you try to post a question with a tag created in the last *n* days, for some value of *n*. I'm not really sure how well that would work in practice, but at least it wouldn't require maintenance "each time that some new technology comes out".

Comment: It is now getting some good quesions

Answer (score 5):

> Or is there nothing we can do to stop these obviously opinionated questions in the future and as always, close and move on?

There is nothing you can do. People will insist on asking these type of question here or on Programmers. All you can do is down-vote, vote to close, and move on.

Oh, and if you see anyone suggesting that the question is asked on Programmers, flag the comment so it can be removed. These question are just as off topic on Programmers as there are on Stack Overflow.